# Geocoder getFromLocation failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, geolocation

I'm trying to get placemarks from coordinates.

I'm using `geoLocator` for that. It was working fine today morning, but now, it throws platform exception.

```
PlatformException(IO_ERROR, A network error occurred trying to lookup the supplied coordinates (latitude: <lat>, longitude: <long>)., null)
```

It says it's a network error, but my device is connected to the internet,

First, i thought there might be some problem in the `Geolocator` package, so i used `Geocoding` package, but the problem persists.

This is the error from geocoder.

```
Geocoder getFromLocation --- mService = android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy@e8c2197, ex = grpc failed, return results = []
```

Please help.

Comment: did u solve this?

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 8):

try to add `localeIdentifier` parameter. works for me. my function code will be like

```
List<Placemark> newPlace = await GeocodingPlatform.instance.placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude,localeIdentifier: "en");
```

Answer (score 7):

See this flutter_geocoding issue (closed): https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geocoding/issues/23

Two solutions presented:

1. create a new emulator
2. stop WiFi on the emulator, restart WiFi and let it find the network (AndroidWiFi)

Solution 2 worked for me.

Comment: thanks, the solution 2 worked for me also

Answer (score 6):

Try to WIPE DATA on your emulator.
Restart it.

It works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Try another emulator (create another emulator as if you are using another android or ios device).
May be the current device that is being emulated is having problems connecting to the internet

Answer (score 2):

its mainly due to change in location of your device if you're using a external device like an android phone then you should reboot your device and it'll work .

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. 
**Reason** - The internet was not working inside my emulator. 
**Answer** - If internet is not working inside your emulator, cold wipe your emulator from the virtual device manager and check again.

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try
stop emulator then
flutter clean
in terminal, then debug again
it will work.
no need to remove the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct reason why this is happening,
[image: From Geocoding package]

and also there is no fix for this at the moment, as far as I have understood the rate gets reset by itself, so just restarting your emulator or app should help you get it back working.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is the problem, but I ended up making a new android emulator(a new emulated device) and it worked fine.